# I have this error when i try to add a product in the cart : "Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."

Tags: laravel, e-commerce, cart

I have a problem with an ecommerce's cart.
In my controller when i use the first() property in my query the product that is added in my cart is always the same, the first that I click.

This is my code:

Controller:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request)
{
    $reference = $request->reference;
    $ean = $request->ean;


    $product = Product::where('ean', $reference)->first();

    if(!$product) {

        abort(404);

    }

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // if cart is empty then this the first product
    if(!$cart) {

        $cart['product'] = [
            'id' => $product->id,
            "ean" => $product->ean,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $product->product_price,
            "reference" => $product->reference
    ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }

    // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
    if(isset($cart['product'])) {

        $cart['product']['quantity']++;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Book added!');

    }

    // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
    $cart['product'] = [
        'id' => $product->id,
        "ean" => $product->ean,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "price" => $product->product_price,
        "reference" => $product->reference                 
    ];

    session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Book added!');
}
```

shop view :

```
<div class="container products">
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Ean</th>
            <th>Prezzo</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach ($products as $product)
            <tr>             
              <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
              <td>{{$product->ean}}</td>
              <td>{{$product->product_price}} €</td>
            <td>
              <p class="btn-holder"><a href="{{ url('add-to-cart/'. $product['reference']) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-center" role="button">Add to cart</a> </p>                  
            </td>                               
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In dd($product) I have this:

[image]

I don't know if the problem is the first() property or it is in the other part of code;
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi. Did you try to debug and look what is in you `$product` variable? For example with `dd($product);`.

Comment: do you have data in your Product table? if not sure please write down dd($product) and show the result, seemss like empty thats why it is showing error.

Comment: Yes, i try and i have all products in my view with products details, and in dd($product) I have details.

Answer (score 0):

make your controller And view backup. check this code. First read
**controller**

```
      public function addToCart(Request $request)
    {
        $reference = $request->reference;
        $ean = $request->ean;//you don't get it. It's waste variable
    
        $product = Product::where('ean', $reference)->first();
    
        if(!$product) {
    
            abort(404);
    
        }
    
        $cart = session()->get('cart');
    
        // if cart is empty then this the first product
        if(!$cart) {
    
            $cart['product'] = [
                'id' => $product->id,
                "ean" => $product->ean,
                "quantity" => 1,
                "price" => $product->product_price,
                "reference" => $product->reference
        ];
    
            session()->put('cart', $cart);
    
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
        }
    
        // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity

        if(isset($cart['product'])) {
    
            $cart['product']['quantity']++;
    
            session()->put('cart', $cart);
    
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Book added!');
    
        }
        else{
//this below code run with your both if statements. if any one statement true then both if statement and this below code run one same time so check this below code your controller and think
        // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
        $cart['product'] = [
            'id' => $product->id,
             "ean" => $product->ean,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $product->product_price,
            "reference" => $product->reference                 
        ];
    
        session()->put('cart', $cart);
    
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Book added!');
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I replace property first() from query with get() I see this error message: 

"Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."

Comment: I did but with the last change now i ha a 404 error page.
But the problem couldn't be the method that I use to access to the collection?

Comment: $product = Product::where('reference', $reference)->first();

Comment: Yeah, but the logic of cart works, because when I click on 'Add to cart' i found the  product inside of cart. But when I click on a second, different product I found in my cart the first product x 2.